# Joomla 3.2.3 featured article ordering

Tags: joomla, article

In Joomla 3.2.3 i can not make the article orders like in J 1.5.x , i want to make the frontpage article ordering like what i define at administrator area.
I try several ways and still do not have any success, 1 weeks already ... :(
The last i tried is this :

```
a) Content => Featured Article => (at top right) sort table by "Ordering Descending"
b) I moved the article in the order i want, then click at "Double arrow" to save it
c) Then i click at "Options" (right top), it will open the Global configuration -> Article page. 
+) Then i click at "Category"  => Choose Layout = Blog,   
+) "Blog/Featured Layout" => Multi column Order = Across. 
+) "Shared Option" => Category Order = No Order, Article Order = Ordering
Date for Ordering = published
Then clicked at "Save and Close"
d) I click at "Menu" => Main Menu => Home => layout
+) multi column order = across,
+) Category order = no order,
+) Article Order = featured article order
```

But at frontend, the article is not changed
it is still ordered by "Date descending"

What is wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is recently reported bug in Joomla. Do a search on joomlacode.org for the issue tracker.

Answer (score 7):

I have J! 3.3.1 and was experiencing the same issue.

Go into the menu manager.  Open each of your menu items and in the "Layout" tab make the following changes:

**Category Order** - No Order (this is the real key to getting your articles ordered the way you want.

**Article Order** - Most Recent (or which ever way you want it ordered.

**Date For Ordering** - I use published but you can use whatever you want.

Do this for each of your menu items and it should fix the problem.

Comment: The default value for "Category Order" is "use Global", suggesting there is a global option which you can set. However, I can't find it under the 'Article Manager Options'. Does it exist?

Comment: The global setting is under the Shared tab.

Comment: hmm... where is the Shared tab? I am trying to order articles in a legacy component called RokStories (shown on the home page). RokStories is set to use the article ordering. However, when I look the articles for the category displayed in RokStories, I don't see the column to order the articles. Will setting the Category order to "no order" for the Home menu item work in my case?

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem. No need to code. Can be done in menus.

1. Article manager click on featured Articles on left hand side. Your Featured articles will appear and a column for ordering shows up. Order accordingly.
2. Go to the Menu Manager to the page you want the featured articles to appear. On the second tab is Layout. go down to Article Order and select "Featured Articles Order" from the drop down. Save and your articles will appear in the order you selected.

Comment: I wanted to avoid making code changes, so I looked at this solution.  Point #2 solved most of the issues, but to do a strictly "Featured Articles Order" list, I had to also disable grouping by category on the Layout tab.  Thanks to @dotnetom and user2615615 for the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 3.3.6 here, I have the same problem, featured ordering always descending no matter what, I changed line 106 in *components/com_content/helpers/query.php* from:

```
$orderby = 'a.featured DESC, fp.ordering, ' . $queryDate . ' DESC ';
```

to:

```
$orderby = 'a.featured ASC, fp.ordering, ' . $queryDate . ' DESC ';
```

Now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ordering of featured articles for the home page. Whatever the order I put it didn't work.

My setup for the Home is

Category Order - No Order

Article Order - Features article order

Thanks to Andrea's tip I changed line 106 in components/com_content/helpers/query.php to

```
$orderby = ' fp.ordering, a.featured ASC, ' . $queryDate . ' DESC ';
```

So sorting by the fp (front page) ordering is always first.

This is surely not the best correction but at least it solved my problem.
for me it looks like a bug in the query construction for the order