# Joomla 3.4.x article ordering

Tags: joomla

I can't seem to get an 'ordering' column in joomla when looking at the articles under a category. I need this to specify the ordering of the articles in a module (RokStories). I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437149/68936) but it did not help - still no ordering column.

Please see this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Also, http://joomla.stackexchange.com. This question is off-topic here.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I guess I posted here because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/24437149/68936 (similar question posted here). Can you (or I?) move the question to joomla.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering column is the first one shown, with the up/down arrow sets. Click the top set (the column heading) to sort by order, and then you can change the order to suit.

Comment: Oooooh, the rows can be re-arranged by dragging & dropping the 3 black dots in that first column. Pretty easy once you figure it out. I was looking for green arrows to move them the articles up & down.

Comment: Good. Now update your site. J3.4 is out of date. https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla!_CMS_versions